# Python dict not printing distinct keys to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am totally blanking on why this is not returning a complete list of distinct keys.

```
input_dict = csv.DictReader(open("./MCPlayerData/AllPlayerData2.csv")) 

def list_keys():
    keys=[]
    for person in input_dict:
        for key in person:
            if key not in keys:
                keys.append(key)
    return keys

print(list_keys())
```

part of the data from AllPlayerData2.csv:

```
achievement.exploreAllBiomes,achievement.mineWood,achievement.openInventory,dyad_number
{"value"=>0: "progress"=>["Forest": "Taiga": "Extreme Hills": "Plains": "River": "ForestHills"]},2,6,1
{"value"=>0: "progress"=>["Forest"]},NA,NA,14
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say "distinct keys"?

Comment: By distinct key I meant all keys are included only once, and not repeated elsewhere in the list.

Comment: OK, and what exactly do you mean when you say "keys"? From what I can see, your code correctly prints out the CSV field names, which is what I think of when you say "keys".

Comment: yes, the CSV field names were what I was trying to print. I thought those were stored as 'keys' within the Dictionary created by DictReader though I may be wrong

Comment: Also, how do you imagine that a dictionary can have not-distinct keys?

Comment: I believe the DictReader returns all keys for the person object (aka each row of my csv)

Comment: Can you show us the output you're getting from the code? I'm running it locally and it's working fine.

Comment: Please first look into: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader . Let us know what is that you are expecting with sample input and output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input_dict = csv.DictReader(open("./MCPlayerData/AllPlayerData2.csv")) 

input_dict.fieldnames
```

will give you the keys you want, see more at [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, cant believe I didnt see it. Thanks!